# how to set selected index to -1 for a flex acm dropdown

Tags: apache-flex, selectedindex, dropdownbox

I am using an acm dropdown and would like to reset the selectedIndex to -1. I am using the following code but it doesnt seem to wrk. Please help. Thank you.

Function used

```
public function Refresh():void
{
   ddlDropDown.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

xml

```
<acm:ComboCheck 
                            id="ddlDropDown"  
                            width="270"
                            prompt="Select values..."   />
<s:Button id="btnClear" width="116" label="Clear" buttonMode="true" click="Refresh();" />
```

Comment: What is acm?  Is the source code for the component available?

Comment: From what I could see this serious source code, https://code.google.com/p/combocheck/source/browse/trunk/combocheck/src/com/acm/ComboCheck.as?r=134   You tried to set the selectedIndex = 0 to see if that is the first